# Handle discriminated union where discriminator is a union type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, discriminator

I am struggling with narrowing a complex discriminated union.

I used a bunch of `if` with early return to eliminate one by one all the case but at the end, I find myself with 2 default type lying on discriminator being union type and the narrowing stop working.

I have a simple snippet demonstrating my issue.

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
  type: 'foo';
}

interface BarBaz {
  bar: string;
  type: 'bar' | 'baz';
}

const func = function (arg: Foo | BarBaz) {
  if (arg.type === 'bar' || arg.type === 'baz') {
    return 'whatever';
  }

  arg; // type Foo or BarBaz expecting Foo
};
```

I guess, I should have only unique discriminator but is there a simple way to get out of this dead end?

Comment: This is [ms/TS#31404](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31404). You need to work around it. For example you could use a `switch` instead as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wE2xZN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh… so a switch works, interesting. Write it up, it's a good answer. I won't be able to use it I think but it might be a good solution for someone else

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDc+yYAngA4SkDkR6H9AvrlyhIsRCgBCcKJIBeOBgCMppClRB0GzNpyVQOyAD7IOSmb1wCh4aPCTJJUZBAAekEABMy9qbPkBILXZjXQ4LQWEbMW85FzdPb2k4OTwA1iCTJNDLBHQQCkIAVxAEZABeQuKwYFzkAAopalIMLCMHQ2iASnkCYBg6hoA6QLLS8oy9QyNB4dGx0w4uvAICKAgwAqgQYwB3AAs4SAA3aHMCSwJB2mQAemvGNLRMZHRHB18XNgQq9Uf0C3ogA) a possible solution?

Comment: For my use case no… I have a function that receive a bunch of different event and I process those differently taking into account there type. Some of those event are treated the same way even if they have a different discriminator.

Anyway thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a design limitation of TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#31404](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31404). While the true branch of your check narrows as expected, TypeScript lacks the sort of counterfactual analysis necessary to do anything useful in the false branch.

If you need this to work without refactoring to a "standard" discriminated union, you'll have to work around it.  One way you can do it is to create a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to discriminate the union explicitly:

```
function discrimUnion<
  T extends Record<K, any>, 
  K extends PropertyKey, 
  const V extends T[K]
>(t: T, k: K, ...v: V[]): t is Extract<T, Record<K, V>> {
    return v.includes(t[k]);
}

const func = function (arg: Foo | BarBaz) {
    if (discrimUnion(arg, "type", "bar", "baz")) {
        arg // BarBaz
        return 'whatever';
    }
    arg; // Foo
    return;
};
```

Or you could change to a [`switch`/`case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement which seems to be better about determining exhaustiveness:

```
const func = function (arg: Foo | BarBaz) {
    switch (arg.type) {
        case "bar":
        case "baz": {
            arg; // BarBaz
            return 'whatever'
        }
        default: {
            arg // Foo
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDc+hYAngA4RkDkx6nDAvrlyhIsRCgBCcKFIBeORgQBG0spWoh6i5C3ZcVUTsgA+yTitl9cg3CDgBbCOVbjkAZQDuwMAgAWCwmQEdBBKIgBXEARkAF4IqLBgEOQACmkaMgwsUykZOFkASgDAwnIvH380qBoAOl0IIrwS5qC4chQAIgMOkm0W1vbkLvye4v7m9LpkAHpp5Fy5PvGCKAgwcKgQMw9fOEgAN2hOJebBZYIAEwh4cIAbMDIm88D0mbmsk-HV9c2GZ7OWgCCIIbHZHM5XAAVNgQADi4WkFzG8QQiWSF2A5AQ1HsAFUQEkQAAeSHICAAD0gIAu5GQACUIMEoBciQBpAA0yDgIGYAD5OayyZSINTaQAFKDodhQFisiDMTnBUJgZAANSFVJpyEhAG1WQBdXkpT4PbWcgDWZA5yBqtv2ZFVOv1BTIKsxyAAopSoIgwCTOQymSzrarebzkYFvhstvsaqAELdwldyCkwDrzc6-oQbIElWEYJFonECwlCal0plMCZ5tI5I1PsAYKkMVicfjCVUaJyOvUOt3uv2RgV689XrMa3lZJ9I2to9tdgcjlnTp9Jm80JhPlHftp+AwhKCHE4XEhkAB5ag0BRCXMhfOF2IotFbTuV7ITusRwiN1Kduow2IYjicxpE4IpjFMP96kA4CLDAkdzjHOYFnyadCG3LZOB2PYIEOQxlxKIESjXcdoKyZB0CgD98iFdhUVoDd0C3Wcd0CPdrCEIA)